# Random select value on array factory Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I had user migration:

```
$table->enum('type',['seller','buyer'])->default('seller');
```

I want when using ModelFactory how to get random value seller or buyer?

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    static $password;

    return [
        'firstName' => $faker->name,
        'lastName' => $faker->name,
        'username' => $faker->unique()->username,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => md5('user123'),
        'bio' => $faker->sentence(3, true),
        'type' => ???,
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Make use of `randomElement` method

```
'type' => $faker->randomElement(['seller', 'buyer']),
```

Comment: Thank you. It working with me.
// returns randomly ordered subsequence of a provided array
randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1) // array('c')
randomElement($array = array ('a','b','c')) // 'b'

Comment: brother, $faker needs to be defined before being used

Comment: I think you can get it with `$this->faker`

Answer (score 11):

Laravel version >= 5.6

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$random = Arr::random($array);

// 4 - (retrieved randomly)

"type" => Arr::random($array);
```

Comment: i used this one and it worked fine

Answer (score 5):

Just in case that anyone is looking for the answer of this question with newer version of Laravel and PHP, you can utilize the `enum` in PHP like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

enum UserTypeEnum: string
{
    case SELLER = 'seller';
    case BUYER = 'buyer';
}
```

and then your factory will look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Enums\UserTypeEnum;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class TaskFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'firstName' => fake()->firstName,
            'lastName' => fake()->lastName,
            'username' => fake()->unique()->username,
            'email' => fake()->unique()->safeEmail,
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password,
            'bio' => fake()->sentence(3, true),
            'type' => fake()->randomElement(UserTypeEnum::cases()),
        ];
    }
}
```

And also if your `type` column is `nullable` you can have your seeder `type` like `fake()->randomElement([...UserTypeEnum::cases(), null])` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Or in another situation it could be

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Category>
 */
class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{

    public static $counter = 0;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {

        $arr_of_categories = ["Ui kits", "Components", "Templates"];
        $category_name = $arr_of_categories[$this::$counter % count($arr_of_categories)];
        $this::$counter += 1;
        return [
            //
            "name"=> $category_name,
            "slug"=> Str::slug($category_name),
        ];
    }
}
```